# Margin displayed differently in IE and Mozilla

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mozilla

Is margin treated differently in IE and Mozilla ? Because when I tried Mozilla 3.6 displaying margin correctly but IE 8 stretching it too far.
Here is my code

```
<div id="searchCriteria">  
<table width="100%" border="1"  bordercolor="#64A4F5">       
</table>
</div>  
<div id="searchResult">
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
#searchCriteria{  
        height:24%;  
        width:100%;  
        float: right;  
        display: block;  
        font-family:  
        verdana,arial;  
        font-size: 12px;
}

#searchResult{  
        height:70%;  
        width:100%;  
        float:right;  
        display:block;  
        margin-top:15px;  
        margin-bottom:5px; 
}
```

Margin between `searchCriteria` and `searchResult` div is getting stretched in IE but working fine in Mozilla.
  (It looks like in IE some space is coming between `table` element and `searchCriteria` div)

Comment: By the way, it is Verdana, not vardana :-)

Comment: Added `height=100%` to `<table>` and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `height=100%` to `<table>` and it works.
Thank you all for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code In FF 3.6.13, IE7-8. I observed the issue only in quirks mode in IE, which probably means that you're either not using a Doctype declration or using IE in quirks mode. If you're using XHTML use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

     <p>… Your HTML content here …</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you're using HTML5 use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

See [this](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) for a list of other Doctype declarations to use.

Comment: It is there.I have added `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` still no luck.

Comment: I am using DHTMLX grid component inside `searchResult` div.

Comment: It looks like in IE some space is coming between table element and searchCriteria div.While margin between `searchCriteria` and `searchresult` is fine in IE.

Answer (score 1):

```
height:24%;
```

Any certain reason to use percent values?

Anyway, I think it's probably [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html). Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` at beginning of document to see if it'll help.

Comment: No its in Standard mode. I have already added `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a stylesheet reset? It's possible browser-inherited margins are conflicting with your design.

Eg.

```
div, table, td, th, tr, {
   margin : 0;
   padding : 0;
   border : 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Here's a link to a more extensive [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

It also may be helpful to use the developer tools (F12 in IE, and the Firebug extension in Firefox) to troubleshoot the discrepancy in your design--if you gather specific information (eg. there's 4px unaccounted for,) you will have a better change at spotting the problem.

P.S. Be extra careful when working with percentages--something like padding will compound the percentage values, resulting in overages. I'm actually not sure if your `border : 1` compounds with 100% (resulting in 100% + 1px,) but just a helpful reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second margin-top declaration to your searchResult div like so :

```
margin-top:10px\9;
```

This will target only IE8 and below. Change the amount of pixel until it looks good to you.